# Do I need to run DITA Toolkit in a server? Is Apache Ant/FOP require a server to run?

Tags: apache, ant, apache-fop, dita

I'm looking into IBM DITA Open source ToolKit for XML document generation. I was wondering the following:
- Does DITA Toolkit require a server to be set up to run?
- Does Apache Ant and Apache FOP require a Server to be set up?

If so then what kind of server needs to be set up?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DITA Open Toolkit does not require a server to run. You can easily install it on a local computer and run it. Apache Ant comes as part of the DITA OT and also does not require a server.

You can run the DITA OT on a server, and many people and companies do this. But that's a different question.